# BeginRequest and EndRequest not working with JQuery FancyBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, fancybox, pagerequestmanager

I am using JQuery FancyBox v2.0.6 to show a sub form as a modal popup. Everything is working fine. The Modal popup is showing as expected. 
But, when I click on the asp.net button which is placed inside the popup window, the events BeginRequest and EndRequest of PageRequestManager are not firing.

The same events are working fine with the button placed outside the modal popup.

Could anyone help me out to fix this issue.

Murahari

Answer (score 0):

I am also stuck on this.  There is an excellent article here http://codingboynamedtracy.com/blog/fancybox-asp-net-web-forms/  but the fix is for fancybox 1.3, and 2.0 is completely rewritten and I can't find appropriate references in the library file.